# How can i insert datatable rows in another datatable at a specified index?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have two data tables with auto generated columns and info from two different Access databases.

The names are:
Export data table (source)
School data table (target)

I want to select the information that the export database has beginning from column 19 (assuming 0=index) and insert that information in the school data table beginning from column 203 (assuming 0-index)

i already tried this method:

```
 try
            {
                cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dataAdapterSchool);
                cb.GetUpdateCommand();
                cb.GetInsertCommand();
                cb.GetDeleteCommand();
                for (int i = 0; i <= 19; i++)
                {
                    DataRow newRow = schoolDb.NewRow();
                    newRow[i + 19] = exportDb.Columns[202 + i];                  
                }
                
                Grid.ItemsSource = schoolDb.DefaultView;
                dataAdapterSchool.Update(schoolDb);
                testbox.Text = cb.GetUpdateCommand().CommandText;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

The problem here is that it gives me the error:
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataColumn' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Which is (according to google) the error that occurs when you don't specify the column names that the source should insert to. Since there are many columns, I want to find a way to do this without specifying the column names.

Any help would be appreciated,

Answer (score 1):

There's an mistake in your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 19; i++)
{
    DataRow newRow = schoolDb.NewRow();
    newRow[i + 19] = exportDb.Columns[202 + i]
}
```

you need to iterate over rows and replace `exportDb.Columns[202 + i]` for `exportDb.Rows[x][202 + i]`

Comment: Thanks, but what does the x represent in exportDb.Rows[x][202 + i] ?

Comment: The variable of the for loop that you need to do to iterate over exportDb.Rows

Comment: I tried what you said, but I get the error that the conversion is wrong. I think I made a mistake in my code, but I can't find it. I did this:

```
 DataRow newRow = schoolDb.NewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i <= 19; i++)
                {
                    foreach(int item in exportDb.Rows)
                    {
                        newRow[19 + i] = exportDb.Rows[item][202 + i];
                    }                                                                      
                }
                schoolDb.Rows.Add(newRow);
```

Comment: with foreach you are iterating over DataRow items, you can do like this:
`foreach(DataRow row in exportDb.Rows) { newRow[19 + i] = row[202 + i]; } }`
or this:
`for(int x = 0; i < exportDb.Rows.Count; x++) { newRow[19 + i] = exportDb.Rows[x][202 + i]; } }`

Comment: Hey! I just tried doing it and it worked. I had the complete wrong vision on solving this problem. Thank you for your help!